# SQL 2016 Standard SP1 - DEADLOCK on same SPID (Exchange Event)

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing, deadlock, sql-server-2016

**Error Message from our log (line breaks added here):**

```
dbo.usp_Replenish_Maintenance_Cleanup : END STEP Table replenish.ProjectionXML;
ERROR : Transaction (Process ID 59) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.,
ERROR NUMBER:1205 during Copy operation. Execution End Time: 2017-03-09 01:17:36.6866667. (Execution Duration: 6 seconds.)
```

This is the 2nd night in a row where this has occurred, and it has only run twice on this platform!  SQL 2014 SP2 CU3 Developer has the ***exact same issue*** albeit on 500K rows for the same table.

Platform is a 2x12-core with 256GB, using a BPE of 512GB, running 2016 SP1.  MAXDOP is 12 per Bob Dorr's "It runs faster" post on Soft-NUMA ([pssql post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/03/30/sql-2016-it-just-runs-faster-automatic-soft-numa/)).  It was MAXDOP=8 for the first run.

An explicit transaction is started part-way into the proc.  The stored proc won't run if it detects @@TRANCOUNT > 0 when started.

The statement is very simple - dynamic SQL, with name substitutions:

```
SELECT r.*
  INTO '+@nFullCleanupTableName+'
  FROM '+@nFullTableName+' r WITH (TABLOCKX)
       INNER JOIN replenish.ActiveEngineRun aer
               ON r.RunID         = aer.RunID
              AND r.InventoryID   = aer.InventoryID
              AND r.SupplyChainID = aer.SupplyChainID
       INNER JOIN tbl_Inventory i
               ON i.InventoryID = r.InventoryID
 WHERE i.ActiveFlag = 1';
```

There are compression, default constraint, create non-cl index and rename statements in the TRAN, ( not in that order).

The table has 48M rows consuming 193GB.

The data file has 216GB free.

I have the deadlock XDL file.

Solarwinds DPA shows only one SPID involved: 1 Victim, 16 Survivors.  Its knowledge base says:

**Exchange Event Lock**
An "exchange event" resource indicates the presence of parallelism operators in a query plan.

When large query operations are "parallelized", multiple intra-query child threads are created that need to coordinate and communicate their activities. To accomodate intra-query parallelism, SQL Server employs this type of lock.

Granularity: N/A

**Deadlock Solutions**

Most intra-query parallelism deadlocks are considered bugs, since technically a session should not block itself, and are often addressed by:
Ensuring that SQL Server is on the latest service pack.
It is uncommon to see exchange event locks in deadlocks. However, if you see it frequently then look for ways to minimize the parallelism of the query. For example:
Add an index or modify the query to eliminate the need for parallelism. Large scans, sorts, or joins that do not use indexes are typical culprits.
Use the MAXDOP option to force the execution of the query to run single-threaded. You can do this by adding "OPTION (MAXDOP 1)" at the end of the query. Consider applying a hint to the plan guide if you cannot modify the query.

*-- End of quote*

This problem makes little sense to me.  Is my only recourse to set MAXDOP=1 for just this table's insert?  There are 5 other tables, all compressed, one of which has 3x the rowcount, that each succeed.  Perhaps it's the nvarchar(max) column (off page) that's giving me the problem (contains XML)...

(Edit: Modified for just the one table, using OPTION ( MAXDOP 1 ) **it runs to COMMIT!**)

Wisdom is sought, please.

**UPDATE** Deadlock graph image [image] and DDL

```
CREATE TABLE [replenish].[ProjectionXML](
    [InventoryID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SupplyChainID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RunID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AdhocRunDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ProjectionData] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [RowStatusID] [smallint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_replenish_ProjectionXML_KeyColumns] ON [replenish].[ProjectionXML]
(
    [InventoryID] ASC,
    [SupplyChainID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [replenish].[ProjectionXML] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_replenish_ProjectionXML_RowStatusID]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [RowStatusID]
GO
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `WITH (TABLOCKX)`?  - just throwing it out there.

Comment: can you paste deadlock graph,along with tables involved and their schema

Comment: TABLOCKX is simply because the original developer wanted complete stability of the data being addressed.  I don't have a problem with it, and the same template dynamic SQL is used on same-size non-compressed tables without issue, IMO it isn't the probable cause of the deadlock.